# mongo / monk - not firing promise.done?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, callback, promise, monk

I'm using mongo/monk to try and get promises to reduce some CB ugliness but it seems to be creating more unusual problems to debug ("now you have two problems").

based off:
https://gentlenode.com/journal/node-4-monk-cheatsheet/45

I have a little routine to clear a collection and insert some data,
however the on.complete or on.success isn't firing

```
    QuizPlugin.collection.remove({}, function(err, doc) {
        Clog.log("QP", "removed"); // get this
        var raw = FileReader.readDataFile(jsonfile);
        var that = this;
        raw.records.map(item => {
            var p = QuizPlugin.collection.insert(item.fields);
            console.log("p.type", p.type);
            p.on("success", function(doc) {
                console.log("done", doc) // never
            });
            p.on("complete", function(doc) {
                console.log("done", doc) // not this one either
            });
            p.on("error", function() {
                console.log("error")  // or this ever show up
            });

            // this method also doesn't emit anything
            // QuizPlugin.collection.insert(item.fields, function(err, doc) {
            //  console.log("inserted")
            // });
            // Clog.log("inserted:", item.fields.question);
        })

    })
```

Is there some other reason the inner `on("success")` aren't firing?
the docs seem pretty clear, if spartan
https://github.com/Automattic/monk#promises

Comment: If it's a promise, it's not an event emitter?

Comment: …at least usually, but now I read their docs :-/